# Thermal printer does not react

Tags: pi-2, serial, printing

I'm (now for some weeks) trying to get a thermal printer (ttl) to work without success.
I've done every step exactly like said [in this tutorial](https://learn.adafruit.com/networked-thermal-printer-using-cups-and-raspberry-pi/overview) but the printer does nothing. Since I don't know how to debug this kind of problem and I also couldn't find any solutions on the web, I hope you can help.

The Hardware:

- RPI2 B
- Thermal Printer - Adafruit #597
- Power supply for the RPI 5V 2.5A
- Power supply for the printer 5V 10A

The Software:

- Raspbian Jessie
- Zijiang ZJ-58 Printer Driver
- Different Packages (see [tutorial](https://learn.adafruit.com/networked-thermal-printer-using-cups-and-raspberry-pi/overview))

---

**EDIT**

`ls -la /dev/ttyAMA0` results in `crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 204, 64 Jul 27 10:47 /dev/ttyAMA0`

`sudo echo "TEST" > /dev/AMA0` has absolutely no effect.

---

Here are the wires:

[image: overview]
[image: connection to rpi]
[image: connection to printer]

---

**UPDATE**

Now It's connected correctly but still isn't reacting to `sudo echo "TEST" > /dev/AMA0`. I think there is nothing broken, because if i boot with serial port enabled, the printer starts to print endless gibberish stuff.

Any idea?

I've just erased the raspbian and started from scratch.

1. Start up and disable Serial => done
2. Restart => done
3. Connect the printer => done
4. Substitute the correct baud rate via `stty -F /dev/ttyAMA0 19200` => done
5. Print test `echo -e "This is a test.\\n\\n\\n" > /dev/ttyAMA0` => **nothing happens**

Comment: If you hold the feed button down, does it print a test page?

Comment: yes. i'm getting a test page.

Comment: what device is your printer in /dev/usb? lp0? Who owns that device file (you can tell by running ls -la /dev/usb/

Comment: What happens if you sudo su to become root and use echo "test" > /dev/usb/lp0?

Comment: @SteveRobillard pls see EDIT. BTW its not a usb printer but a ttl (serial gpio)

Comment: Are you certain you did this correctly: "The transmit/receive lines *will cross:* **the TX pin** on the printer connects to **RXD** on the Pi, **RX** on the printer to **TXD** on the Pi"?

Comment: @goldilocks yes. I'm sure, i did all the steps exactly like said in the turorial. If you could check my edit in a few minutes, i'll upload a photo.

Comment: Did you disable the console on Raspbian? It may be blocking the hardware UART.

Comment: @ppumkin yes, i've disabled the serial console

Comment: Goldilocks may have noticed that you put the serial connector on the wrong pins. Shift the connector down one pin, so you have 2 free pins (the 5V) then re-enable the console to see if it spits out garbage or text. If not.. then RMA it as dead on arrival, wait for a new one. It happens to everybody.

Comment: did you try with sudo before each command?

Comment: Yep. I've tried sudo

Answer (score 3):

The connector on the pi is in the wrong position.  It's starting at the second pin down on the outer row, which is a 5V power pin, so the other two pins connected to the TTL jack on the printer are GND and TXD.

Presuming the black wire is for ground and that cable was built to cross the lines properly (it is impossible to tell which pin is which on the printer, but the jack seems to fit in only one way, so if it came supplied from Adafruit it should be correct), then you want to move it one pin down, so there are *two* pins above it (considering the short end of the board with the USB & ethernet jacks as "below").

If you look at [the full size image from the Adafruit guide](https://learn.adafruit.com/assets/31834) this is easier to see (also there are lots of [diagrams of the breakout online](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVvsB.jpg) explaining what each pin is; going by that one you wanted pins 6, 8, and 10, not 4, 6, and 8).

Since the pi is still running I don't *think* accidentally attaching 5V to the ground of the printer will have damaged anything (although see ppumkin's comment below for a more refined opinion about that); I think it would have effectively disabled the serial connection.  The major risk here would be shorting the 5V to ground, but if that happened the pi would be junk now.

However, since this means they were connected TX to TX, if the printer did output a wacky signal voltage then the UART may be damaged.  If you connect it properly and it works, then no harm was done.  Again presuming the cable crosses over properly, the middle wire yellow wire would have been from the Pi's GND to the printer's RX, and that is harmless (it also means the printer's RX line would never have gone high, so chances are it did not even consider there to be any connection on the TTL port).

Comment: Ahh drats. If the OP put 5V it may have blown a fuse on the printer :( I mean the only way is to re-enable the system console and connect the pins properly, the expected outcome should be printed garbage. If nothing then you need to see if there is a fuse near the 5V on the printer and try to fix it.

Comment: maybe I have plugged it in the wrong way only the last time. I'll check it tomorrow (it's late here). Hopefully it's going to work. Many thanks anyway.